# Define a compact set $\mathcal{X}$ such that $x(t) \in \mathcal{X}$ for all $t \geq t_0$

Tags: general-topology, nonlinear-analysis

I have state vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{n}} $, that behaves following this inequality

$
\|x(t)\|\leq c_1\|x(t_0)\|\exp(-c_2(t-t_0))+c_3
$

where $c_1, c_2, c_3$ are positive constants. This inequality shows that $x$ converges to the ball $c_3$ as time passes.

Suppose $x_0$ is in a compact set $\mathcal{X}$, now I want to define a compact set $\mathcal{X}$ such that $x(t) \in \mathcal{X}$ for all $t \geq t_0$

Comment: What you are asking is very unclear

Comment: $c_3$... (i) - what is the meaning of the dots? Just to produce some distance between $c_3$ and (i)? What are domain and codomain of $x$?

Comment: @Didier Sorry. It would be helpful if you state what is missing

Comment: @PaulFrost Sorry, (i) was my mistake. I deleted it to avoid the confusion. $x$ is state vector $x \in \mathbb{R}^{\text{n}} $

Comment: To clarify: You want to define $\mathcal X$ such that $x(t) \in {\mathcal X}$ for all $t \geq t_0$?

Comment: @BrianTung Yes, Exactly

Comment: Think about a closed ball centered at the origin.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thank you, I wanna hear in detail. You mean the ball $c_3$ is in the center of $\mathcal{X}$? What would it look like mathematically?

Comment: $c_3$ is a scalar. I suggested a ball centered at the origin. What should the radius be so that $x(t)$ is in the ball for all $t\ge t_0$?

Comment: @TedShifrin How about the radius =$c_1\|x(t_0)\|+c_3$? If so, x(t) seems in the ball for all $t \geq t_0$

Comment: Yes, perfect. (Closed ball, of course.)

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks a lot. Please answer and end this post, defining $\mathcal{X}$ mathematically :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just set $\mathcal X = \overline{B(0,c_1\|x(t_0)\|+c_3)}$. This is a compact set containing $x(t)$ for all $t\ge t_0$.

Comment: Thanks a lot. but I have one question why there's a bar above? cuz that means the complement set. To contain $x$, the one without the bar seems correct

Comment: Bar means closure (so we’re talking about the closed ball). Occasionally bar is used to denote complement in some introductory texts, but it’s an appalling choice of notation.

Comment: Wow I didn't know that. Thank you, you teach me a lot